# using strcpy to copy a string to a member of a structure via the pointer operator

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, strcpy

I'm trying to use strcpy to set values for a char array which is the member of a structure. I want to do this using the pointer operator if possible.

```
struct my_struct{
  char foo[15];
} *a_struct_Ptr;

int main(){
  strcpy(a_struct_Ptr -> foo, "test");
return 0;
}
```

I can compile this code but when I go to run it I get a segmentation fault.

Also it seems to work fine if I don't define the struct as a pointer, for example the following code works fine...

```
struct my_struct{
  char foo[15];
}a_struct;

int main(){
  strcpy(a_struct.foo, "test");
  return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to do this with pointers though.
Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Because you are pointing to nothing.  You need to allocate memory for it.

Comment: `a_struct_Ptr` doesn't point at anything; it holds NULL so your code most probably crashes.  Allocate enough space for the structure and you'll be in with a chance.

Comment: It looks like you need to define the struct as a variable and allocate some memory for that struct.  For example: struct *my_struct = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct)); possibly.

Comment: Thanks, further question though... Does that mean that by defining a struct explicitly, the compiler will automatically handle allocating all the necessary space as defined in the struct?

Comment: @MattHall - yes, by defining a struct variable (vs. a struct pointer), memory would be automatically allocated on the stack (if it's a global variable, it will be allocated differently, but still automatically).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem as many commented, was that I didn't allocate memory for the pointer to my structure.

By preceding my strcpy statement with

```
a_struct_Ptr = (struct my_struct *) malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct));
```

I was able to successfully copy a string literal to the char array member of my_struct.

As is good practice, I added `free(a_struct_Ptr);` after the struct is done being used.

Comment: I would probably add a mention to `free`, so that OP knows to free the memory once it's no longer in need.

Comment: Glad this helped!